# Mapping doc2vec paragraph representation to its class tag post-training

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, text-classification, doc2vec

I have trained Doc2Vec paragraph embeddings on text documents using the `Doc2Vec` module in Python's `gensim` package. Normally each document is tagged with a unique ID, yielding a unique output representation, as follows (see [this link](https://fzr72725.github.io/2018/01/14/genism-guide.html) for details):

```
def tag_docs(docs, col):
    tagged = docs.apply(lambda r: TaggedDocument(words=simple_preprocess(r[col]), tags=[r.label]), axis=1)
    return tagged
```

However, you can also tag a group of documents with the same tag in order to train class representations, which is what I did here. You can query the number of output representations with the following command:

```
print(model.docvecs.count)
```

My question is as follows: I trained the model of `n` classes of documents, yielding `n` document vectors in `model.docvecs`. Now I want to map each document vector to the corresponding class tag. How can I establish which vector is associated with which tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `classA` was one of the document-tags you provided during training, then `model.docvecs['classA']` will return the single doc-vector that was learned for that tag from training.

If you have another new vector – for example one inferred on new text via `model.infer_vector(words)`, then you can get a list of which learned doc-vectors in the model are closest via `model.docvecs.most_similar(positive=[new_vector])`.

If your true aim to classify new documents into one (or more) of these classes, then taking the top `most_similar()` result is one crude way to do that.

But  having reduced all classes to just a single summary vector (the one vector learned for that tag), then taking just the one nearest-neighbor of a new-document, may not perform well. It somewhat forces an assumption that that classes are very simple shapes in the n-dimensional space.

For classification, you may want to let all documents get individual vectors (not based on their known classes, or in addition to their known classes), then train a separate classifier on that set of (doc-vector, label) labeled-data. That could discover finer-grained, and oddly-shaped boundaries between the classes.